# shared memory in c, question about the output

Tags: c, pointers, shared-memory

I tried to realize shared memory with C, but I came up with a problem with my output.

I tried to make a thread called TA put the grade into a shared memory space and make "student" thread output the grade.

In the TA thread:

```
const int SIZE = 4096;
const char *name_ta = "Students_Information_ta";    
int studentGrade = (int)((random() % (100 - 80 + 1)) + 80); // TA gives out a grade to a student
char *grade = (char *)&studentGrade;

/* shared memory file descriptor */
int shm_fd_ta;
/* pointer to shared memory object */
void *ptr_ta;

/* create the shared memory segment of ta */
shm_fd_ta = shm_open(name_ta, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
/* configure the size of the shared memory segment of ta*/
ftruncate(shm_fd_ta, SIZE);
/* map the shared memory segment of ta in the address space of the process */
ptr_ta = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd_ta, 0);
if (ptr_ta == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("Map failed\n");
    return -1;
}

/* write to the shared memory region */
sprintf(ptr_ta, "%d", grade);
ptr_ta += strlen(grade);
```

And here is the output sentences in student thread:

```
/* name of shared memory object */
const char *name_ta = "Students_Information_ta";
/* size of shared memory object in bytes */
const int SIZE = 4096;

int shm_fd_ta;
void *ptr_ta;

/* open the shared memory segment of ta */
shm_fd_ta = shm_open(name_ta, O_RDWR, 0666);
if (shm_fd_ta == -1)
{
    printf("shared memory failed\n");
    exit(-1);
}

/* map the shared memory segment of ta in the address space of the process */
ptr_ta = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd_ta, 0);
if (ptr_ta == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("Map failed\n");
    exit(-1);
}

printf("The grade assigned by the TA is %d\n", ptr_ta); // student receives a grade
```

I thought it should gave me the grades which are numbers between 80 and 100, but in fact the output is some very large numbers like 251142144. Perhaps it has output the address. What can I do to fix this mistake?

Comment: What do you think this does: `char *grade = (char *)&studentGrade;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *grade = (char *)&studentGrade;
```

Okay, so `grade` is of type pointer to character but is pointing to an integer. Not sure why you'd want to do that, but okay.

```
sprintf(ptr_ta, "%d", grade);
```

You told `sprintf` to print an integer but you passed it a pointer to a character that points to an integer. The `sprintf` function certainly has no idea what to do with such a mismatched pointer, especially when you told it you were going to pass it an integer.

Why not:

```
sprintf(ptr_ta, "%d", studentGrade);
```

If you tell it you're going to give it an integer, maybe give it an integer.

--

```
ptr_ta = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd_ta, 0);
if (ptr_ta == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("Map failed\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Now, `ptr_ta` is a pointer to the string you printed.

```
printf("The grade assigned by the TA is %d\n", ptr_ta); // student receives a grade
```

You told `printf` you were going to pass it an integer, but instead you passed it a pointer to a string. How is that supposed to work?

I'd change a lot of things, but this is a start:

```
printf("The grade assigned by the TA is %s\n", (char *) ptr_ta); // student receives a grade
```

Comment: Also, why `ptr_ta += strlen(grade);`? Since `grade` is not a string, why are you passing it to `strlen`? It's a pointer to an integral value, right?

Comment: Thank you, it gives me the number between 80 and 100 now, but... it gives me 81 every time, could you please tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Yes, it is a pointer to an integral value... so, I should use something else like `sizeof`?

Comment: @Crow0913 Read the documentation for `random`. It will give you the same sequence each time unless you seed it differently. Since you wrote a string to the shared memory, if you want to find the next bit of shared memory after the string, you need to add the length of the string. But `grade` is the integer, not the string.

Comment: So, I should try to replace the `grade` with a string...?